# How do you 301 redirect links in Drupal via the .htaccess modredirect rules to keep spidered links?

Tags: 7, migrations, redirection

I am migrating a site to a new domain and I would like to do a 301 redirect via the .htaccess file to create a redirect rule. I have over a 1000 dynamic links generated via views so this isn't do able with a redirect module as easily. I just want to get an example modrewrite rule to put in my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also have a look at the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module. Managing redirects in the database might have some advantages over putting them in a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i put in my .htaccess file:

I wanted to redirect urls from: www.abc.com/buy/tennis/shoes/1232

TO: www.xyz.com/buy/tennis/shoes/1232

Line 100:

```
RewriteRule ^buy(/?.*) http://www.xyz.us/buy$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: You have to put this rule above the other rewriterules. I put it below the rewriterule ^ index.php and broke the site. just an fyi as I'm not exactly sure why it broke. if someone else can shed some light on this it would be great.